# Add-PnPField how to set it to be a required field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

```
# CREATES NEW FIELDS FOR PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE
Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Squad Number' `
  -InternalName SquadNumber `
  -Type Number `
  -Required:$true `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'
```

I can't get the required parameter to actually work, it still says this field is not required when running my PowerShell script. Any advice to get this working?  `-Required:$true` is set to true?

Comment: i think it should be `Required $true` , i.e replace colon with space or simply specify `-Required`

Comment: Thank you will give it a go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
# CREATES NEW FIELDS FOR PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE
Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Squad Number' `
  -InternalName SquadNumber `
  -Type Number `
  -Required $true `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'
```

**OR** (As given [here](http://www.codesharepoint.com/powershell/create-list-column-in-sharepoint-using-powershell)),

```
# CREATES NEW FIELDS FOR PLAYER BIO CONTENT TYPE
    Add-PnPField `
      -DisplayName 'Squad Number' `
      -InternalName SquadNumber `
      -Type Number `
      -Required `
      -Group 'Football Content Types'
```

**official documentation**: [Add-PnPField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps) - Check `-Required` under **Parameters** section.